# Android Canvas always drawing a blackscreen

Tags: java, android

i've a problem canvas always draw a black screen no matter what i want to draw.
no matter when i want that the contentview is the View class or i take a layout and
add the class or i let the canvas draw a background and so on

```
public class GameSurface extends SurfaceView {

private SurfaceHolder holder;

GameThread gameThread;
Bitmap background;

public GameSurface(Context context) {
    super(context);
    holder = getHolder();
    gameThread = new GameThread(this);
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background1);


    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameThread.setRunning(true);
            gameThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            gameThread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry){
                try {
                        gameThread.join();
                    retry = false;

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(background,0,0,new Paint());
}
}
```

Rebuild and clean brings nothing!

Whats the Problem?

Thank You!

Comment: As per my knowledge by default background of any View is transparent. As you are drawing image , check the transparency level of image background. This type of issues comes when images are not having transparency. Please check

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to tell me. it's a normal background what matter what it shows but alwas its all black more not and only when i call canvas drawing...maybe it's a bug? i'm using android studio

Comment: Check transparency of image that you are using, check with UX guys